# Invalid backend model when installing Zitec: Site Branding

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting this error on my shop after i install and delete Zitec: Site Branding package.I hope someone could help me out..

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zitec-site-branding-1.html

It wont work on 1.9 and RDW Theme..

Invalid backend model specified: scena/catalog_attribute_backend_cimage

Trace:

```
0 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
1 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(205): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()
2 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(998): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->_setAttributeValue(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Array)
3 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(959): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_loadModelAttributes(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
4 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), '2', NULL)
5 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), '2', NULL)
6 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php(167): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('2')
7 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(278): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->getCurrentCategory()
8 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(249): Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer->_isActiveMenuCategory(Object(Varien_Data_Tree_Node))
9 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(218): Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer->_addCategoriesToMenu(Object(Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection), Object(Varien_Data_Tree_Node), Object(Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu), true)
10 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer->addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
11 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer), 'addCatalogToTop...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
12 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
13 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
14 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(34): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->getHtml('level-top')
15 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/dutchkey/...')
16 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
17 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
18 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
19 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
20 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
21 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
22 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', true)
23 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(84): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu')
24 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/dutchkey/...')
25 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
26 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
27 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
28 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
29 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
30 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/3columns.phtml(49): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
31 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/dutchkey/...')
32 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
33 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
34 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
35 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
36 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
37 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
38 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
39 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
40 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
41 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
42 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
43 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
44 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
45 /home/dutchkey/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
46 {main}
```

@Update manage products

Invalid backend model specified: scena/catalog_attribute_backend_image

> #0 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
> #1 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Type/Abstract.php(176): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()
> #2 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Type/Product.php(57): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid_Type_Abstract->_isAvailableAttribute('adminhtml/catal...', Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute))
> #3 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Type/Product.php(80): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid_Type_Product->_isAvailableAttribute('adminhtml/catal...', Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute))
> #4 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Type/Abstract.php(201): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid_Type_Product->_getAvailableAttributes('adminhtml/catal...')
> #5 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid.php(504): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid_Type_Abstract->getAvailableAttributes('adminhtml/catal...', false)
> #6 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid.php(534): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid->getAvailableAttributes()
> #7 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid.php(1235): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid->getAvailableAttributesCodes()
> #8 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Observer.php(554): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid->checkColumnsAgainstGridBlock(Object(BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid))
> #9 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Rewriter/Eval.php(32) : eval()'d code(93): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Observer->afterGridPrepareCollection(Object(BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid))
> #10 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
> #11 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
> #12 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
> #13 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #14 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
> #15 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
> #16 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product->getGridHtml()
> #17 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/dutchkey/...')
> #18 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
> #19 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
> #20 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
> #21 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
> #22 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
> #23 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #24 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
> #25 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #26 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
> #27 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
> #28 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/dutchkey/...')
> #29 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
> #30 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
> #31 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
> #32 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
> #33 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #34 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
> #35 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/local/HN/Pin/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/ProductController.php(182): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
> #36 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): HN_Pin_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->indexAction()
> #37 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
> #38 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #39 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #40 /home/dutchkey/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #41 /home/dutchkey/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #42 {main}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the table `eav_attribute` for a record with `backend_model = 'scena/catalog_attribute_backend_cimage'` and delete the row.
Clear the cache when you are done.

**[EDIT]**
I took a look through the extension code.
To completely uninstall the extension you need to remove the tables `zitec_branding_store` and `zitec_branding`. and remove the extension from the `core_resource` table` with

```
DELETE FROM `core_resource` WHERE `code` = 'zitec_branding_setup';
```

The extension does not add any product or category attributes. My hunch is that you have an other extension that is responsible for this error.
I see that you have an extension called `BL_CustomGrid` that has an `eval` in it. Never use extensions that have `eval` in their php code. Even if they might work, they are very dangerous.

Comment: I was wrong, its not a 100% fix.

Comment: in the magento admin page (manage products and category) i stil get a error @Marius

Comment: did you clear the cache? You should look in the install/upgrade scripts of the extension and see what attributes it ads. And remove them all from the db. You can also contact Zitec about this. They are nice guys and gals. They will answer.

Comment: @DennisUrsem. See the update on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve that error like this.
I go to my phpmyadmin, searched "eav_attribute", sort by attribute_id, the last one has the "catalog_attribute_backend_image" name and I just deleted the line, and Viola ! the home page reborn.